# How to change column layout for contact us page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml

I want to change contact us page layout from current 2columns-rightlayout to 1column layout, i have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is two method to do that

**Method 1**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/contacts.xml
```

copy to your theme

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/contacts.xml
```

change

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
```

to

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

**Method 2**

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/local.xml
```

if there add below or else create new `local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <contacts_index_index>
            <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        </contacts_index_index>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 6):

Open your theme's `contacts.xml` file,

located In:

**app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/[your_theme_name]/layout/contacts.xml**

And find this node `<contacts_index_index>` action and find

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
```

replace it with below code :

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

Answer (score 3):

your layout handle is

> contacts_index_index

Next, find the layout handle in your contacts.xml file

```
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
    <label>Contact Us Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

Change the setTemplate call to reference your template

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
</reference>
```

Alternately, add the handle reference to your local.xml file. The local.xml file is applied last, so whatever goes in there "wins"

```
<layout>
    <contacts_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>    
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
</layout>
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: clear cache is required.